# Downloaded SQLite database and leak warnings

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver

I've made an application that uses a downloaded SQLite database. To retrieve data in it I'm using a `ContentProvider`. When I need to read the database, I always (I've checked at least five times) use a code like this:

```
Cursor c = getContext().getContentResolver().query(MyContentProvider.ITEMSURI,
        projection,where,null,null);
if(c.moveToFirst()){
    while(!c.isAfterLast()){
        itemsList.add(cursorToItem(c));
        c.moveToNext();
    }
}
if(c!=null) c.close();
```

But I keep getting many errors like this (I make a sequence of queries in a for loop):

```
10-18 13:16:01.709: W/SQLiteConnectionPool(27704): A SQLiteConnection object 
for database '/storage/emulated/0/MyAPP/mydb.sqlite' was leaked!  
Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to 
close the database when it is no longer needed.
```

What could cause all these warnings? Cursor is always closed and in `ContentProvider` there's no need to close database.

**Code:**

This is the class that manages the database:

```
public class OpenMyDBHelper{

    private static final String DB_NAME = "mydb.sqlite";
    private static final File DB_PATH = new File(
            MyAppFolderManager.getInternalMemoryFolder(), DB_NAME);

    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    public SQLiteDatabase open() {
        db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH.getAbsolutePath(), null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        return db;
    }

    public void close() {
        db.close();
    }

}
```

And this is my `ContentProvider` subclass:

```
public class MyContentProvider extends ContentProvider {

    private OpenMyDBHelper db;
    //static paths/Uri definitions....


    private final static int ITEMS = 1;
    private static final UriMatcher sURIMatcher = new UriMatcher(
            UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
    static {
        sURIMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, ITEMS_PATH, ITEMS);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        db = new OpenMyDBHelper();
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
            String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
        Cursor cursor = null;
        SQLiteDatabase database = db.open();
        int uriType = sURIMatcher.match(uri);
        switch (uriType) {
        case ITEMS:
            cursor = database.query(Constants.TABLE_ITEMS,
                    projection, selection, selectionArgs, null,null,
                    null);
            cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), ITEMSURI);
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI (" + uri + ")");
        }
        return cursor;
    }

    @Override
    public String getType(Uri uri) {
        return null;
    }

    //It's just a read-only db, I don't need the CUD operations...

    @Override
    public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection,
            String[] selectionArgs) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What could cause all these warnings?

The fact that you keep re-opening the database. Open the database *once*, in `onCreate()`, not on every `query()` call.

Though, in all honesty, if you are not implementing the full CRUD operations, I'd just dump the `ContentProvider`, as you are gaining nothing by it. It might also allow you to avoid doing a bunch of `query()` calls in a loop and significantly improve performance, by using `IN` operators and such in a SQLite query.

Comment: Thank you both for the solution to my problem and for the smart advice to make my app faster! In 4 minutes I'll accept this anwser

Answer (score 1):

If you have to use getReadableDatabase many times:

You can use this.close to close your database from leak.
Example :

```
   public String getAdditionalInfo(final int id) {
        yourDB = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = yourDB.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            return cursor.getString(0);
        }
        cursor.close();
        this.close();// You add this line
        return "";
    }
```