# How to close Cursor in getContentResolver for update method on android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, cursor, android-contentresolver

Hi in my project I'm updating the database in for loop using the `getContentResolver` method. This is the coding I'm using for update the database

```
for(VOShoplyRetailer retailer:retailerMasterList){
            ContentValues retailerCV = retailer.parseToContentValues();
            int affectedRows = context.getContentResolver().update(DataContract.RetailerMasterEntry.RETAILER_MASTER_CONTENT_URI,
                    retailerCV,
                    DataContract.RetailerMasterEntry.COLUMN_RETAILER_ID+" = ?",
                    new String[]{retailer.getRetailerId()}
            );
        }
```

and I'm getting error as

`03-20 11:55:45.279    6777-6786/com.example W/SQLiteConnectionPool﹕ A SQLiteConnection object for database '+data+data+com_example+databases+example_db' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.
03-20 11:55:45.299    6777-6786/com.example W/CursorWrapperInner﹕ Cursor finalized without prior close()`

How to close the cursor in getContentResolver (or) how to fix this error.

Comment: where do you use ContentResolver.query() ?

Comment: read this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26439370/downloaded-sqlite-database-and-leak-warnings). probably you open database not only once

Comment: there is not query i'm just update using update method

Answer (score 0):

Inside your ContentProvider implementation of update, close the database before you return .. perhaps something like

```
SQLiteDatabase db = yourDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
int rowsAffected = db.update(table, values, whereClause, whereArgs);
db.close();
return rowsAffected;
```